# Impossible to maintain Jquery vertical slider size to the same height than the picture next to it

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the [screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk1oY.jpg)

As you can see, the vertical slider on the left doesn't match with the size of the picture. Besides I needed to use the  `min-height: 80vh` trick for the slider CSS, else the slider was too small (and the picture were floating outside their div).

Is there a way to achieve to maintain the same size between the picture and the slider ?

Here is my html code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
            <div class="wrapper" align="right">
                 <div id="slider-vertical" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11" style="position: relative;">         
          <img src="images/mur02-1200.jpg" class="superpose" id="img1" alt="mur01" style="visibility:visible;">              
          <img src="images/mur03-1200.jpg" class="superpose" id="img2" alt="mur02" style="visibility:hidden;">
          <div id="square" class="squarePosition"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the css

```
#slider-vertical {

  min-height: 80vh;
  max-height: 100%; 
}

.superpose {
  position: absolute;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-right: 40px;
  top: 20px;

}
```

Comment: If `#slider-vertical` should have `min-height: 80vh`, how would you expect it to have the same height as picture, when picture's height is very small (1px for example)?

Comment: Picture's height won't be 1px. (At least 300px)

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting you to use `display:flex` for the parent node.

```
<div class="row slide-container">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
            <div class="wrapper" align="right">
                 <div id="slider-vertical" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11" style="position: relative;">         
          <img src="images/mur02-1200.jpg" class="superpose" id="img1" alt="mur01" style="visibility:visible;">              
          <img src="images/mur03-1200.jpg" class="superpose" id="img2" alt="mur02" style="visibility:hidden;">
          <div id="square" class="squarePosition"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide-container {
  display: flex;
}

#slider-vertical {
  height: 100%
}
```

This is my solution for equal height for multi child columns without fixed height. [Url](https://www.theknot.com/registry/macys-registry). Refer to the `In-Store Offerings` section, `.photo-card-container` class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gabriel. Nevertheless with this technic, the vertical slider becomes just a square http://pasteboard.co/2d4tacKeE.png

Comment: Have you set 100% height for the wrapper and the column? Have you set the width of it? Or have you set the `float:left` for the child node?